# docker image to use docker utilities

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is there any docker image which can be used to do all docker utilities command mostly push and pull. I need to use docker under pod container and looking for specific docker image.

I tried installing docker cli under the container, read commands work fine like docker cp nd docker images, but docker push nd pull doesn't work stating docker service is not running.

Comment: How do you connect to the daemon from the container?

Comment: Commonly referenced as Docker in Docker or short _"dind"_: https://hub.docker.com/_/docker

Comment: "If you are still convinced that you need Docker-in-Docker and not just access to a container's host Docker server, then read on." - OP seems to only want a CLI to interact with an *existing* daemon.

Comment: why do you need docker in docker? ci/cd pipelines?

Comment: There's a bit of a chicken-and-egg problem here – if you're trying to use a separate Docker container to invoke Docker commands, you need some way to invoke that container, and if you can do that, then you can just do whatever Docker thing directly without the intermediate container.  I'd suggest using a [language-native Docker SDK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/) rather than the `docker` CLI tool (or better still, do all container management outside your application proper).

Comment: Well, even I am aware that is not the recommended approach but I have a requirement to upload docker images to GCP running through Jenkins pipeline. Jenkins pipeline works in pod fashion. I cannot install directly anything on pod container so ultimate approach was to build a image with dockerfile and push the built image into gcp.

Answer (score 0):

You need an image with docker daemon inside or with docker client which connects to some remote docker daemon which can run anywhere (including other container)

You can also use [docker:dind](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) image which contains docker client&daemon:

```
docker run -d  --privileged --name docker docker.io/docker:20.10.23-dind
docker exec -it docker sh
/ # docker version
Client:
 Version:           20.10.23
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.18.10
 Git commit:        7155243
 Built:             Thu Jan 19 17:30:35 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.23
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.18.10
  Git commit:       6051f14
  Built:            Thu Jan 19 17:36:08 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.6.15
  GitCommit:        5b842e528e99d4d4c1686467debf2bd4b88ecd86
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.4
  GitCommit:        v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d1
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Comment: As noted in comments on the main question, actually using a Docker-in-Docker container isn't usually recommended.

Comment: i believe it's ok for ci/cd processes

Comment: The [traditional answer](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/) is that, even for CI setups, it's probably not what you want.